# How to write this Digamma Symbol in Latex?

Tags: symbols, unicode, unicode-math

Specifically I want to write these in LateX:

[image]

Unicode name: Mathematical bold small digamma
Codepoint (hexadecimal): 0x1D7CB
Codepoint (decimal): 120779
In unicode block: Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols

[image]

Unicode name: Greek small letter digamma
Codepoint (hexadecimal): 0x03DD
Codepoint (decimal): 989
In unicode block: Greek and Coptic

[image]

Unicode name: Latin capital letter f with hook
Codepoint (hexadecimal): 0x0191
Codepoint (decimal): 401
In unicode block: Latin Extended-B

I am using TeXstudio, so I can compile in pdflatex, xelatex, or lualatex and some other ones.

What is the simplest possible way to do this? I don't care about the nitty-gritties of how various compilers work -- I just want a simple command and the environment in which that command gives the desired output.

Comment: `amssymb` provides `\digamma`

Comment: `MinionPro`  and `mathdesign` also have a digamma.

Comment: Please add images rather than links. Not dismissing other people's work quite so blithely is also recommended, but courtesy is not always a requirement for receiving an answer.

Comment: @William I think it would be a lot fairer to say that the more effort is put into a question, and the easier it is to answer it, the faster answers will come and the better they will be. Now, in general, links are especially problematic as people (including me) would rather not follow them, because of security concerns. I don't follow links if I can help it and certainly not to sites I don't know. It's also just nice if questions can be self-contained. What if that link goes dead? Your question is worthless

Comment: @William Even though you dislike the `amssymb` version, this is what [Digamma looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma).  It essentially boils down to finding a font which has a Digamma glyph in your preferred shape, because the Unicode code point it readily available at the link you posted.  I suggest you search the web for Unicode math fonts and browse their character table.

Comment: The MathDesign fonts have [this shape](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQsAB.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Free Serif](https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/) has your desired glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\DejaVuSans{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontface\FreeSerif{Free Serif}
\def\Fhook{\mbox{\DejaVuSans\char"0191}}
\def\digamma{\mbox{\DejaVuSans\char"03DD}}
\def\mbfdigamma{\mbox{\FreeSerif\char"1D7CB}}
\begin{document}
\Fhook \digamma \mbfdigamma

$\Fhook \digamma \mbfdigamma$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: U+0191 is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F WITH HOOK; U+03DD is GREEK SMALL LETTER DIGAMMA; U+1D7CB is MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL DIGAMMA. There are also U+03DC GREEK LETTER DIGAMMA and U+1D7CA is MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL DIGAMMA. Curiously, there's no “non bold” variant.

Comment: @egreg Is there just no *non-bold* in the font or in Unicode as a whole?

Comment: @HenriMenke only bold mathematical digamma (it was added to support the ISO entity set isogrk4) the non bold entity had already been mapped to U+03dd and getting another character in without the ISO entity backup is (or was) tricky..