# How to use (missing) digamma with GFS Porson?

Tags: xetex, unicode, greek, xgreek

With xeTeX and GFS Porson I can't use the digamma (ϝ) in text mode though the font seems to have the character (U+03DD GREEK SMALL LETTER DIGAMMA, UTF-8: 0xCF 0x9D, UTF-16: 0x03DD). Or is this a mathematical symbol? A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313222/how-to-write-this-digamma-symbol-in-latex) doesn't help, I don't want to switch to a math font, as it does with `\digamma` if I load `\usepackage{mathspec}` or don't prevent `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` from loading.

PS: GFS Porson doesn't actually have a digamma, I was mistaken. A replacement is not automatically chosen, so I want to select the character from a similar font.

Easiest sample (including some of the other things which didn't work)

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: xetex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}
% \usepackage{mathspec}
% \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0370}{{\digamma}}
\newunicodechar{ϝ}{\greekfont^^^^0370}
\begin{document}
% \begin{greek}
  μῆνιν ἄειδε θεά \digamma ,\\
  ϝ\\
  {\char"C3}\\
  \symbol{^0370}\\
  \textdigamma
% \end{greek}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but GFS Porson does not have ϝ.  I looked with [fontforge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ynX0.png).  The ϝ slot is highlighted in blue.

Comment: You could use [CMU Serif](https://ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode) instead.  The advantage it, that you can use it as the main document font, because it has Latin *and* Greek alphabets (as well as Cyrillic).

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry, I just used Gucharmap and looked into some porson-files, there the digamma *seemed* (for unexperienced eyes) to be included.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue (a non-existent glyph) that cannot be solved.

Comment: @Mico I'd agreed if egreg hadn't just mentioned something very useful.

Comment: You should perhaps rephrase your question a little.  As is, it might suggest to other users that there *is* a digamma glyph in GFS Porson even though there isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a font with the required glyph (not GFS Porson, which hasn't it) and use `\newunicodechar` for choosing it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{GFS Porson}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{GFS Porson}

\newfontfamily\digammafont{Libertinus Serif}
\newunicodechar{ϝ}{{\digammafont\itshape ϝ}}

\begin{document}

μῆνιν ἄειδε θεά ϝ

\end{document}
```

Don't load `xltxtra`: possibly the only feature one could need is `sscript`, that you disable. The fewer contortions, the better.

You may want to adjust the scale for the substitute font you choose.

[image]