# How to achieve uppercase Digamma in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, greek, amssymb

For example, what I want to use is the `\Digmma` symbol
But LaTeX does not have this symbol,
Hope you can make it happen, that is `Ϝ` This symbol!
Take a look at the picture below:

[image]

That's right, this is it.

Comment: Additional material: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669888/how-to-type-all-math-alphanumeric-symbols-in-unicode-in-latex

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663560/using-the-greek-letters-koppa-stigma-sampi-digamma-heta-san-in-cm-font and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313222/how-to-write-this-digamma-symbol-in-latex

Comment: and also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670021/how-to-print-all-greek-and-copitc-unicode-with-latex

Answer (score 1):

As with your last question,  you can use unicode input or command forms, this with lualatex. Of course you need a font that has the character

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\begin{document}
$\Digamma + \upDigamma + Ϝ$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although the uppercase Digamma can be realized, it is not the original font of LaTeX!

Comment: @gopoke you keep asking the same question over and over again for different characters. there are hundreds of thousands of Unicode characters. No font has them all. You obviously have to choose a font that has the characters you want.

Comment: Then you think of a way, maybe there is a way to realize the uppercase Digamma and then add the original LaTeX font!