# How to print all Greek and Copitc Unicode with LaTeX?

Tags: unicode, greek

Take a look at the picture below:
[image]

Just what I'm going to use `Greek` alphabet!

PDF link: https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf

Comment: What exactly want to do? To output this image as it is or just to print the greek alphabet? Or just to write a text in greek?

Answer (score 3):

as for your other questions you just need suitable fonts. With luatex I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}

αβγ

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's nice, but you don't fill the whole Greek and Coptic Unicode characters, and it's not the original LaTeX font!

Comment: @gopoke obviously it is not the original tex computer modern as that font has no Greek letters. You could use a larger font such as Noto Serif to cover a larger range than TeX Gyre if you need that. Or perhaps NewComputerModern has enough characters and closer in style to classic tex fonts

Comment: You can use Symbola or Latin Modern Math fonts,
If Latin Modern Math does not support Unicode, the Symbola font can be used!